# редактирование non-public классов

Tags: java, android-studio

Начал изучать Java и наткнулся на то, что не могу редактировать некоторые классы в Android Studio. Пытаюсь расковырять некоторые проекты с гитхаба.
Покопался в самой среде и в гугле, не нашел ничего, понятного новичку.

Answer (score 0):

Какие классы вы не можете редактировать? Классы самого языка (Java) вы редактировать не сможете. Так же как и классы сторонних зависимостей, которые подключены не как модуль проекта, а как уже скомпилированные классы.

Если кратко - редактировать можно только не скомпилированные классы.

Comment: То есть скомпиленый класс нужно писать с нуля и потом им замещать имеющийся?

Comment: @Tiny_Octopus, если нет возможности другой, то да. Язык править вам вряд ли надо, а вот сторонние зависимости - можно попробовать подключить иначе и тогда можно править. Но всё в каждом случае индивидуально. Скорее всего вам просто не нужно править те классы, которые вы не можете править. в 95% случаев это бессмысленная работа.

Comment: Как раз язык и редактирую, решил одну программку для своих нужд приспособить, а чтобы было проще проследить наследование и лишний раз посидеть перед прогой начал локализацией заниматься